# How can I zip all files in the same directory under some condition?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I would like to create a bash script that compresses the files in a folder, for example:

```
/home/<username>/Desktop/Folder
```

And for that, if I'm not mistaken, you could do something like this:

```
zip -r Folder_2021-Jan.zip /home/<username>/Desktop/Folder
```

But there is one condition: the files to be compressed must be older than 30 days.

I have no idea how to add that condition to the script. I've searched but haven't found anything similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use find with -mtime to check for files older than 30 days

```
find /home/<username>/Desktop/Folder -maxdepth 1 -mtime +30 -type f -exec zip Folder_2021-Jan.zip '{}' +
```

Search for only the directory /home//Desktop/Folder and no child directories for files only (type -f) and then execute zip on as many returned entries as possible, using + and {} as a place holder for entries.